# Unable to SSH into EC2 server after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an ubuntu 18.04 based EC2 instance using an Elastic IP Address. I am able to SSH into the instance without any problems.

apt is executing some unattended updates on the instance. If I reboot the system after the updates, I am no longer able to SSH into the system. I am getting the error `ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Connection refused`

Few points:

1. Even after the updates, I am able to SSH before the reboot
2. Method of restart does not make a difference. `sudo shutdown -r now` and EC2 dashboard have the same result.
3. There are no problems with sshd_config. I've detached the volume and attached it to a new working instance. `sshd -t` did not report any problems either
4. I am able to do `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service` after the updates but before the system restart.
5. I've tried with and without Elastic IP. Same result
6. From the system logs, I see that SSH is trying to start, but failing for some reason

I want to find out why the ssh daemon is not starting. Any pointers?

Update:

1. [System Logs](https://pastebin.com/NgiaX8YF)
2. [Client Logs](https://pastebin.com/E2ajF2PN)
3. No changes in the security groups before and after reboot

Comment: Can you get the log and put it in paste bin?

Comment: Use `-vvv` to obtain logs, and then please add them to your Question. For example: `ssh -vvv -i key.pem ubuntu@1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the error `Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.` in system logs. The solution given at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301750/ubuntu-16-04-failed-to-start-create-static-device-nodes-in-dev helped solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

EC2 > Network & Security > Security Groups > Edit inblound rules > SSH 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: `Connection refused` is an indication that the destination computer was successfully reached, but the connection was rejected. If the problem was due to the Security Group, it would say `Operation timed out`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: EC2 > Instances > Actions > Image and templates > Create image

Step 2: Launch a new instance using the AMI image.